# Correct way to copy a pointer-type string variable to a array of chars string variable?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I think my question makes clear just by reading my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    char *strpointer;
    char strarray[500];

    strpointer = (char*)malloc(500 * sizeof(char));

    strcpy(strpointer, "This a string");
    strcpy(strarray, strpointer);

    printf("strpointer is: %s \n", strpointer);
    printf("strarray is: %s \n", strarray);
    return 0;
}
```

As can be seen (or so I think, I am rather new to C programming), I am just trying to **copy a text** inside a variable `strpointer` that is defined as pointer to char, into a variable `strarray` that is defined as array of char.

This program seems to be working all right, but, as long as pointers are still a bit complex for me, I am not sure of not messing things.

May I use this approach for this kind of strings copying?

Comment: You can use this approach, but it's not clear to me what your question actually is.  If you want to have two copies of a string, `strcpy` is a reasonable choice.  `strncpy` is usually a better choice.  You can also use `memcpy` or `memmove`, or `bcopy`.  If you want a writable copy of the string, calling malloc and copying into the memory is reasonable.  Often, people make many more copies of a string than they actually need.  Try to avoid that.

Comment: Indeed, @WilliamPursell , having a writable copy of the string was my main purpose.

Comment: No, you should never use `strcpy()` and just assume that the source will fit in the destination. If you want to copy a string to an _array_, just use `snprintf`: `char buf[512]; char *str = "..."; ... if(snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s", str) >= sizeof buf) err(1, "the string would not fit in");`. And instead of using fixed sized buffers, you can use `strdup` or `asprintf` and `free()` the buffer after having used it. NEVER use `strcpy`, `strncpy`, `strlcpy`, `strcat`, `strncat`, `strlcat`, etc.

Comment: And btw, you should 1) check the return value of malloc 2) NOT cast its return pointer 3) not multiply the size by `sizeof(char)` (which is always 1).